# Better tag than "immunology" for immunocytochemistry et al?

Tags: discussion, tags

So, a question of mine: [Recommended applications for commercial antibodies](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/183/149) was edited to add the `immunology` tag. I'm all in favour of improving the tagging (my original ones were fairly pathetic) but this strikes me as muddying the waters.

I would interpret `immunology` as being to do with studying the workings of the immune system, whereas this question was about experimental protocols that happen to make use of immune system processes without investigating them.

So I've deleted that tag for now, though I won't fight the point further. But maybe we could do with an `immunocytochemistry` tag or something like that? I'm not sure that quite fits either...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you that definitely `immunology` is irrelevant in your case. I would either go for something a tad generic like `techniques` or I actually quite like `staining`.

Otherwise we could choose of having `ICC` and `IHC` tags, which I would hope would be quite common anyway.

Comment: I suspect that [tag:staining] is too broad to be really useful, you can stain tissues, cells, proteins, RNA, DNA ... and most of those methods are pretty different.

Comment: Well, but that's why you have multiple tags...

Answer (score 4):

I agree that [immunology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunology) is not the right tag for asking about the usage of antibodies in the lab.

For questions about antibody use in the lab the tag [antibody](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antibody) might be good enough. This specific question is not about any technique in particular, so that is the only tag that fits.

Though I think in most cases the tag that should be used would be the specific technique that is used, for example [affinity-chromatography](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affinity-chromatography), [western-blot](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-blot) or [immunocytochemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunocytochemistry).